# How do I make username and password file in android

Tags: android

I take two `EditText` and one `Button`. I want to set a particular username and password, and when I click on the `Button` if the username and password is correct then open a new intent otherwise display a toast.

I use this code to display different toast but it not works. it always display "incorrect".

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if((e.getText().toString()=="nishant")&&(e1.getText().toString()=="pawan")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "correct",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "incorrect",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: So many answers. All of them is correct. Please mark an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try again like this，change “==” with “equals”：

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if((e.getText().toString().equals("nishant"))&&(e1.getText().toString().equals("pawan"))){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "correct",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "incorrect",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals()` to compare Strings

```
e.getText().toString().equals("nishant")
```

`==` only compares references.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use `==` to compare two Strings, Use `.equals("")` for that and Write below code instead of your code, it will solve your problem.

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getText().toString().equals("nishant") && e1.getText().toString().equals("pawan"){
            Intent mInSecond=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(mInSecond);
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
.equals()
```

like this:

```
e.getText().toString().equals("nishant")
```

`==` is used to compare Strings, where `.equals()` compares two value.

See the below code:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if((e.getText().toString().equals("nishant"))&&(e1.getText().toString().equals("pawan")))
        {
            Intent mInSecond=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(mInSecond);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "incorrect",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals()`

```
e.getText().toString().equals("nishant")
```

`.equals()` compares value equality

Also when you are comparing the strings. Be aware of uppercase or lowercase because sometimes it happens we repeate our mistakes again and again and we dont know about that...